# High enough value in small range

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant0}$ be a continuous function s. t. $f(x) = f(x+1)\;\forall x\in[0,1]$. Suppose that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1$.

Let $A:=\left\{y\in[0,1]:\int_y^{y+\frac{1}{2}}f(y)dy\geqslant \frac{1}{2}\right\}$
.

What is the least possible measure of $A$?

The measure of $A$ can be arbitrarily close to $0.5$ if the function has a spike to the right of $0$ and another one to the right of $1$, and is zero everywhere else. If $0.5$ is the right bound, it seems that the proof should go by some kind of averaging argument. But it is not easy to construct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a,b)\subset (0,1)$ is an interval where $\int_y^{y+0.5} f(x)dx \lt 0.5$, then $(1-a,1-b)\subset (0,1)$ is an interval where the integral is greater than $0.5$ because of the periodicity of $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. I missed this simple argument which is specific to $0.5$. Is there a way to generalize it if $A$ is defined as the set of $y$ such that $\int_y^{y+0.6}f(y)dy\geq 0.6$?

Comment: Yes, this is specific to $0.5$.  I don't see a simple way to generalize it, but there may be.  I think your idea of a spiky function is a good challenge, but making a lot of small spikes may let you stay just below $0.6$ for more of the interval.

Comment: Thank you. Since you answered the posted question, I upvoted and accepted it, and instead post the variant with $0.6$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615172/value-bound-for-continuous-periodic-function). Interestingly, it seems that the answer may still be $0.5$.