# Difference over interval for periodic-like function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and nondecreasing function such that $F(0)=0$ and $F(x+1) = F(x)+1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, $F(0.4)=F(0.5)=0.5$ and $F(0.9)=1$. Let $A(F,a)$ be the set containing all $x\in[0,1)$ s. t. $F(x+0.4)-F(x)\geq a$.
>
> What is the largest $a$ such that the Lebesgue measure of $A(F,a)$ is always at least $0.5$?

Note that $A(F,0) = [0,1)$, so the largest $a$ is nonnegative.

Without the extra condition on the values of $F$, it could be that $F$ shoots up from $0$ to $1$ around some point in $[0,1)$, which will imply that the largest $a$ is $0$. But this condition means that the increase in the value of $F$ needs to be somewhat spread out over the interval, which disallows such functions.

A related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615172/value-bound-for-integrable-periodic-function), where we want to find the smallest size of $A(F,0.4)$ (without the new condition).

Comment: In fact, $F$ being piecewise continuous *does* incorporate the case in which $F$ jumps from $0$ to $1$ at some point. So for this new question, it might be easier to restrict the set of functions to be coutinuous ones.

Comment: @Saad Thank you, I changed to continuous.

Comment: Use `$\to$` for the output $\to$ instead of `$\rightarrow$`

Answer (score 1):

The following example provides an upper bound for the sought $a$. In particular, $a$ cannot be larger than $\frac{5}{14}$ in general.

Consider the following piecewise linear function defined on $[0,1)$ as follows
$$
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{10}{7}x &\text{for } x \in \left[0, \frac{7}{20}\right)\\
\frac{1}{2} &\text{for } x \in \left[ \frac{7}{20}, \frac{1}{2} \right)\\
\frac{10}{7}x-\frac{3}{14} &\text{for } x \in \left[ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{17}{20} \right)\\
1 &\text{for } x \in \left[\frac{17}{20}, 1 \right).
\end{cases}
$$
(this function $F$ is defined so that it passes through the given values at $0$, $\frac{2}{5}$, $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{9}{10}$).

It is a straightforward computation to show that
$$
A(F,a) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{for } a \leq \frac{5}{14}\\
\frac{7}{4}-\frac{7}{2}a &\text{for } a \in \left( \frac{5}{14}, \frac{1}{2} \right)\\
0 &\text{for } a \geq \frac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}
$$
which proves the claim $A(F,\frac{5}{14})=\frac{1}{2}$.